# How to achieve a annotation that the annotation is @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE) in Java

Tags: java, annotations

I want to achieve a annotation likes @Override.
If the effect of custom annotation is to check whether the method has a parameter list.

I have implemented a custom annotation like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface HasParameterList {}
```

And next how should I do,it will check whether the method has a parameter list when compiling source code。

Comment: You need to use java reflection api

Comment: Please learn Annotation Processor by yourself. http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101